# Calculation puzzle 012

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

What's A + B = ?

[image: a+b=?]

I found A=60 and B=63x4=252, thus A+B=60+252=312; but, source says that's wrong answer.

Source: This question was asked in YTU exam for int'l students in 2018. I have discussed about them in my other posts.

> Possible answers are: 158, 204, 112, 148 and 168. Correct one is commented by @Damila below, I don't want to write it here. Thanks.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance @garakchy but what are those directional signs other than the arrow?

Comment: These arrows are part of the puzzle, I believe.

Comment: IMO this is a poor puzzle as not enough information is given to be able to 100% determine both the black circle and the white diamond. They could be a couple of things, both which change the answer.

Comment: Your answer seems to follow perfectly valid logic. Was this question multiple choice, like many of the others - and do you have the answer options to work backwards from?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil If you have alternate solutions to the question, this is exactly what the OP wants to see.

Comment: Maybe it's not x4 but +45, the other arrows are all sums, aren't they?

Comment: Is the answer 168?

Comment: @DEEM yes they can be comprehended the way you like as long as you can solve the puzzle. They are there just to indicate the connection between the numbers.

Comment: @Damila exactly. Can you elaborate your answer below? If that's logical I'll accept it as correct. Thank you.

Comment: @Stiv Yes, multiple choice. I have added the options now. Thanks.

Comment: See Paul Panzer’s comment.

Comment: @asg wow, that's very good approach. Now, I understand the solution. Didn't read all the comments, my bad. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulPanzer you should post that as an answer. Because it is. And it's correct :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the apparent relation between the shapes of the arrow heads and the operation they imply is a red herring. And even if they aren't there is no reliable clue as to what open versus filled heads may signify.

> The simplest rule is that each kind of arrow means to add a fixed number. Evidence would be that the numbers given never go down and that the black triangle and diamond add to the same increment $7$ at two places. The increment needed for the open diamond would then be $45$, hence $A=60;B=108;A+B=168$.

Answer (score 2):

Occam's razor says the simplest explanation is the best.

> The "arrows" can be decoded in a simple and consistent way:
>   - Black means addition, white means multiplication.
>   - The number of vertices of the arrowhead seen as a polygon indicates by how much.
>   In the process you find A = 60, B = 252 and A+B = 312.  Just as you did.
>   It is not even difficult to find.
>
>   But your source says it is wrong.
>
>   There are different possibilities.
>   - Either this solution works just by chance and there is another better explanation,
>   - the solution is correct and your source is mistaken.
>   - there is a typo in the problem statement.
>
>   To me it is clear that the 1st possibility is such an extraordinary coincidence that the truth must be in the last 2 explanations.
>
>   Among these explanations, it seems more likely that there is an error in the formatting of the problem statement
>   rather than in the transcription of the answer the source refers to.
>
>   So my (updated) conclusion is: it is an error in the problem statement.
>
>   For example, it is possible the last arrow was meant to have a triangular head.
>   We have enough information to understand that it should mean "times 3".
>   And the solution would be A=60, B=3x63=189, A+B=249.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Unfortunately, your answer, like mine, is not even included in the options. I have added the options now. @Damila's answer is correct, I hope he/she writes his/her solution here. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, I saw the intended solution.  That would be possibility number 4: there are multiple possible answers but it is intentional.  You must use the possible answers to find the correct one.